# R download files from ftp server in Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, ftp, google-cloud-platform, rstudio-server

everyone

I am running RStudio Server on a Google Cloud VM with Ubuntu 14.04 (see complete `sessionInfo` at the end). I am trying to download a number of files from a ftp server, and the first step is to list the subdirectories within the server, for which I am using the `RCurl`package:

```
library(RCurl)

getFiles <- function(dirs) {
urls <- paste(dirs, "/", sep="")
fls <- strsplit(getURL(urls, dirlistonly=TRUE), "\r?\n")
ok <- sapply(fls, length) > 0
unlist(mapply(paste, urls[ok], fls[ok], sep="", SIMPLIFY=FALSE),
     use.names=FALSE)
}

dirs <- "ftp://ftp.mtps.gov.br/pdet/microdados/RAIS"
folders <- getFiles(dirs)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
Failed to connect to ftp.mtps.gov.br port 21: Connection timed out
```

I ran the same code locally, on my Windows machine, and it went perfectly.

Apparently, the VM is not being able to establish a connection with the ftp server for some reason involving Linux (I did some research, and some people are using `getBinaryURL` instead of `getURL`, but I haven't been able to figure out how to apply it to my code...) Can somebody give me a light?

Here's the detailed `sessionInfo`from the VM:

```
R version 3.3.0 beta (2016-03-30 r70404)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8        LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
```

Comment: did you check if you need to use pasv ftp instead of "active"?

Comment: Hi, @MarcB. I'm sorry, can you clarify it a little more, please? I don't have much experience handling Linux machines...

Comment: it's an ftp protocol thing. standard ftp has client->server connections for sending commands, but receiving data server->client requires the server to connect to the client, which isn't possible in a lot of cases, so there's "PASV" ftp, which only has client->server connections.

Comment: @MarcB, I tried to use the command `quote PASV`to check whether the connection is passive, but the command won't return anything, as the connection wasn't even established...

Comment: then something's blocking ftp entirely, which means you need to figure out what.

Comment: when running on cloud platforms, often times IP addresses will get classified as "malicious" due to things that were previously running on those addresses. Spin up another google cloud host and try again and try the same process on AWS and DigitalOcean. I'm a cybersecurity researcher and this is sadly how many "threat intelligence" block lists operate these days.

Comment: Hi, @hrbrmstr, thank you for your answer. I am not sure that's the case, since the FTP server from which I am trying to download the files is sponsored by the government. (The data is about national employment statistics in Brazil)

Comment: If you're running in Google Cloud, it matters not who the sponsor is. Unintelligent block lists are unintelligent block lists.